# Unable to append events to EventStoreDb from a Lambda due to a RpcException DeadlineExceeded

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, eventstoredb

I have a simple AWS lambda in C# with netcoreapp3.1 that tries to append some events to a stream in EventStoreDb using gRPC client (`EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams`).

Locally, (outside the AWS Lambda) I can use the same functionality properly against my remote EventStoreDb. When deployed as AWS Lambda I get the exception

```
{
  "errorType": "RpcException",
  "errorMessage": "Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail=\"\")",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at EventStore.Client.Interceptors.TypedExceptionInterceptor.<AsyncClientStreamingCall>b__5_0[TRequest,TResponse](Task`1 t)",
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()",
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)",
    "at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)",
    "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
    "at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)",
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)",
    "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
    "at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.AppendToStreamInternal(AppendReq header, IEnumerable`1 eventData, EventStoreClientOperationOptions operationOptions, UserCredentials userCredentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
    "at EventStoreDb.LambdaSample.EventStore.Append(String streamName, Int32 aggregateVersion, IEnumerable`1 events, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /mnt/c/src/issue-lambda-eventstore/src/EventStoreDb.LambdaSample/EventStore.cs:line 25",
    "at EventStoreDb.LambdaSample.LambdaEntryPoint.FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in /mnt/c/src/issue-lambda-eventstore/src/EventStoreDb.LambdaSample/LambdaEntryPoint.cs:line 52",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ]
}
```

The issue can be reproduced, I've added the code here: https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/issue-lambda-eventstore
along with instructions on how to deploy/run lambda function with AWS CLI.

Please notice that the instructions refer to a role with an ARN that may be different in your case, and it's using my `--profile diegosasw` which you have to modify in your own AWS CLI

The code is in the repo, but as a summary, this is the simple function that fails

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
    context.Logger.LogLine("Get Request\n");
    context.Logger.LogLine("Storing sample events in event store");

    var eventStoreClient = EventStoreClientFactory.Create(ConnectionString);
    var serializationService = new SerializationService(SupportedTypes.Default);
    var eventStore = new global::EventStoreDb.LambdaSample.EventStore(eventStoreClient, serializationService);
    var foo = new Foo("First event");
    var bar = new Bar( "Second event");

    var events = new List<object> {foo, bar};

    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    var streamName = $"SampleLambda-{id}";
    
    // this is my own wrapper function
    await eventStore.Append(streamName, events.Count, events, CancellationToken.None);
    
    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Body = "Events persisted successfully",
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
    };

    return response;
}
```

---

UPDATE: I've also created it here: https://discuss.eventstore.com/t/grpc-core-rpcexception-deadlineexceeded-in-aws-lambda/3174

Comment: Have you got any success on this? I have the same problem, reading over TCP works but not when moving to gRPC.

Comment: Not using lambda anymore (moved to AWS Fargate and containers). Couldn't find out the reason but I thought it's something with lambda being restricted to make external calls. I'm surprised reading over tcp works.

Comment: Well TCP works with the older (deprecated) ClientAPI. My error was not to set Http Port as connection for gRPC.

Comment: did you manage to access event store from a lambda? If so, please feel free to add an answer showing how to and I'll mark it as the selected one. In my case the event store was accessible when running the app outside lambda as a standard kestrel app from my localhost, therefore the Event Store was reachable. Not sure what's needed to have it working within lambda.

Comment: No, I did not go into this direction.

Comment: I will try it out soon :)